# Put some variable in json response inside Aspect

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, aop, aspect

We want to add some variabale in json response, but inside aspect.

we need to do something similar to what is done in this function but instead of with the request it would be with the response.

Comment: Miguel, it is not very polite to ask a question and then not react to an answer. @sansay61 answered just 20 minutes after you asked, and yet you neither commented on nor accepted his correct answer. This way you are not going to make a lot of friends here or motivate others to answer your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want exact impl or just the direction? if the direction, then annotate your method with custom annotation to get rid of patterns and do something like this:

```
@Around("@annotation(FQAnnotationName)")
public Map<String, Object> aroundSomething(ProceedingJointPoint jointPoint){
   Map<String, Object> resultOfMethodExecution = (Map<String, Object>) jointPoint.proceed();  
   //do something with the result returned
   return resultOfMethodExecution;
}
```

Here `@Around` is used to wrap invocation within your aspect. Typecast the result of target method, modify it in the way you want and return.

This is just an approximated solution, do not judge it as an exact implementation of what you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).